# How to convert IMediaSeeking.GetCurrentPosition in seconds in DirectShow?

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

I'm trying to retrieve current video position from IMediaSeeking interface. The time format set to TIME_FORMAT_MEDIA_TIME and documentation says that GetCurrentPosition return 100-nanosecond time units for this format. What code I need to convert returned value to seconds or TimeSpan? I've tried this code but it gives too high values.

```
TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time / 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milli, Micro, Nano -> divide it by 1000 more.